# How to use jQuery and Ajax to return just one string and how to insert it to a DDL in a jdialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jdialog

I'm trying to create a dynamic module where I drop an object on screen. Then a jQuery dialog opens with three drop-down lists. When I select a value in the first drop-down list I'm trying to filter the results in the next list via Ajax.

This is my JS code:

```
$("#ddlTableType").live(
        'change',
        function() 
        { 
            var GetTablesCodes = $.ajax({
                url:'AjaxActions/TableCodes.aspx?ObjectType=' + $("#ddlTableType").val(),
                async:false                 
            }).responseText; 
          //alert(GetTablesCodes);
          //alert(GetTablesCodes.$('#hidCodesList').val());
          //alert($('#hidCodesList').val());
        }
   );
```

In the ASP.NET page I'm doing the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TableCodes.aspx.cs" Inherits="AjaxActions_TableCodes" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hidCodesList" runat="server" />
</form>
```

The code behind for this page:

```
public partial class AjaxActions_TableCodes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dsCodesList = DbHelper.ExecuteDataSet(
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnStr"],
                        "spObjectCodesByTYpe_Select",
                        new SqlParameter("@ObjectType", Request.QueryString["ObjectType"])
                );

    hidCodesList.Value = "";
    for(Int16 CodeListIndex=0;CodeListIndex<dsCodesList.Tables[0].Rows.Count;CodeListIndex++)
    {
        hidCodesList.Value += dsCodesList.Tables[0].Rows[CodeListIndex]["Value"].ToString() + ",";
    }
}
```

}

In my first call to alert I get the entire page. In that I can see the hidden field filled with the data I need. How can i extract this data? Finally, all the drop-down lists are in a JDialog so maybe that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General Answer on ASP.NET jQuery and Cascading Drop-down lists

From what I can discern from your question the user experience you are trying to create is a *modal popup* (via jDialog) which contains a series of *cascading drop-down lists*. There are quite a few ways to put this paradigm into use. Using the search terms "[cascading drop-down lists asp.net](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cascading+drop+down#hl=en&expIds=17259,18168,24999,25907,26262,26714,26781,26993&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=cascading+drop+down+asp.net&cp=22&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=cascading+drop+down+as&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7c8f32f65b860aba)" will net you a lot of examples on how to put the various solutions into practice.

Here are a couple of articles which may help

- [Great Article On Cascading DropDown List and jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/jaredroberts/archive/2009/08/28/great-article-on-cascading-dropdown-list-and-jquery.aspx) (no Ajax all client side)
- [Building Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net Using jQuery and JSON](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/jQuery/224_Building_Cascading_DropDownList_in_ASPNet_Using_jQuery_and_JSON.aspx) (an Ajax example)

### More Specific to your problem

Essentially you want to load a modal popup via jDialog which contains three drop-down lists. You should bind to the `onchange` event of the first drop-downs. The bound function should use jQuery to call a web method which returns the data to fill the next drop-down.

[edit]
The article linked above ([Building Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net Using jQuery and JSON](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/jQuery/224_Building_Cascading_DropDownList_in_ASPNet_Using_jQuery_and_JSON.aspx)) shows an example of how to append options to a drop-down list via JSON and the append method of a jQuery object. I've pulled out the pertinent append code.

```
$("#ddlCities").append($("<option></option>").val(this['ID']).html(this['City']));
```

[/edit]

Comment: 10x for the answer, i understand the algorithem and that is what i posted, i've binded the first DDL to the event(as shown) and call for for the ajax method to fill the second one, just don't know how to create the data (the right way i mean, i'm creating the correct data in the ajax call but don't know if it the right way do to it) and how to get the data from the ajax return into a javascript that i can use to fill the next DDL....